# Create an array of strings inside the brackets from right to left

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create an array of the texts inside brackets fom right to left. So if we have this text:

```
const text = "I was sent [to earth] for the [next time]"
```

Then the desired result would be:

```
["next time", "to earth"]
```

So far I just find the regex to select the inside of the bracket:

This is the prototype (not the code I'm looking for):

```js
const text = "I was sent [to earth] for the [next time]"

const result = text.replace(
        /(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/g, // this is the regex to select inside of the brackets
        'inside bracket'
 );

 console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not a dupe because OP wants not just matching strings inside `[...]` but also wants matches from right to left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match (with look arounds) + reverse`:

```js
const text = "I was sent [to earth] for the [next time]"

var arr = text.match(/(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=\])/g).reverse()

console.log(arr)
//=> ["next time", "to earth"]
```